# Passing a bash script variable to a quoted value in backticks

Tags: bash, jira, jq

Unrelated: This has been doing my head in.

Below is a curl function that works as below (I've put it on multiple lines for readability):

```
fixVersionQuery='https://thejirainstall.com/jira/rest/api/2/project/ON/versions?';

myJSONResponse=`curl -u username:password -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
--insecure --silent $fixVersionQuery |jq '.[] | {id,name} |  \       
select(.name=="Version-1.2.3") | .["id"]'`;
```

The above works. However, I want to be querying a version whose name I'm passing to the function. So `"Version-1.2.3"` might be a variable such as `"${JIRA_FIXVERSION}"`. The problem is that within the line above, I can't figure out what combination of apostrophes` back ticks or quotes to use. Although I know that the general structure of the function will be...

```
JIRA_FIXVERSION;
fixVersionQuery='https://thejirainstall.com/jira/rest/api/2/project/ON/versions?';

myJSONResponse=`curl -u username:password -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
--insecure --silent $fixVersionQuery |jq '.[] | {id,name} |  \       
select(.name=="'$JIRA_FIXVERSION'") | .["id"]'`;
```

The above exits with a compile error on `"'$JIRA_FIXVERSION'"` or ${JIRA_FIXVERSION} if I use that.

Comment: What error are you getting from that example? That should work assuming the value of `JIRA_FIXVERSION` is a simple version string (not quoted, etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,

I got it in the end. So

1. I have an alias which points to the bash file. The file receives a variable which must be passed in quotes:

`$jiraReleases "Version1.2.3"`

2. The file takes the variable:

`JIRA_FIXVERSION=$1`

3. Wthin jq the quotes are escaped, and additional quotes and apostrophes are added. Note that the below line is also surrounded by single quotes and backticks.

`.[] | {id,name} | select(.name=='\""${JIRA_FIXVERSION}"\"')`

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you just need to quote the double quotes (so that they are left alone by the shell as literal characters). The shell will normally substitute variables within backticks, and I suppose you just want to have the double quotes around the expanded JIRA_FIXVERSION, so that a command like the example you gave is produced (which contains `"Version-..."`).

Example:

```
$ XX=bla; echo `echo kklkj | sed s/kk/\"$XX\"/g`
"bla"lkj
```

or, indeed, simpler:

```
XX=bla; echo `echo \"$XX\"`
```

-> "bla"